# Data does not display on first try only upon refresh

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to node, express and mongo so I need some guidance. I set up a mongo database with 3 objects. I created an application with a route so that http://localhost:3000/Employeeid  will lead the page to display all the 3 objects in the database, which the page does. However for each subsequent refresh, the same data gets displayed multiple number of times based on the number of refresh. (i.e. For the first refresh, the data duplicates once. For the second refresh, the data duplicates twice.) Does anyone know what may be wrong?

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
var str = ''

 app.route('/Employeeid').get(function(req, res) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, client) {
        var db = client.db('EmployeeDB')
        var cursor = db.collection('Employee').find()
        cursor.forEach(function(item) {
            if (item != null) {
                str = str + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Employee id&nbsp&nbsp;' +
                item.Employeeid + '</br>'
             }
        })
        res.send(str)
        client.close()
    })
})

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {})
```

Comment: You need to put _var str = ''_ inside the route to have an empty string every time you query it.
You should also put your database connect outside of the route and store the _client_ object that you can use for any calls you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending to `str` every time the `/EmployeeId` route is called. To fix this, move `str` inside the callback:

```js
app.route('/Employeeid').get(function(req, res) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, client) {
        var str = ''
        var db = client.db('EmployeeDB')
        var cursor = db.collection('Employee').find()
        cursor.forEach(function(item) {
            if (item != null) {
                str = str + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Employee id&nbsp&nbsp;' +
                item.Employeeid + '</br>'
             }
        })
        res.send(str)
        client.close()
    })
})
```

Side note - you should reuse the Mongo connection instead of calling `connect` and `close` on every request.

Answer (score 1):

The Reason why your getting duplicate results is you are not making `str = null` after sending the result. you are concatenating  `str` for each request because `str` is a global variable.  your code can be modified for performance as like this.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express() 
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
var str = ''
var db = null
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, client) {
    if( err ) {
       throw new Error( err );
     }

    db = client.db('EmployeeDB') // we are storing db reference in global variable db

    });

app.route('/Employeeid').get(function(req, res) {
    db.collection('Employee').find().toArray( function(err, cursor){
       if( err ) {
                res.send('');
                throw new Error(err );
       }

       cursor.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item != null) {
            str = str + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Employee id&nbsp&nbsp;' +
            item.Employeeid + '</br>'
         }
    }
    res.send(str)
    str = '';


  })

})
})

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {})
```

If you don't move `res.send()` into callback function you may send result before getting data from db due to async nature of node.

Comment: Are we storing the db in a global variable so that we can reuse the Mongo connection?

Comment: Yes . we are storing db connection in global variable so that we can reuse it.